# pagination from filtered search

Tags: jquery

I am doing a search in jQuery:

```
$('#MainContent_myTable tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td:eq(0)').not(':contains(' + filterVal + ')').parent().hide();
});
```

I'd like to be able to do some quick pagination (without a plugin) from the rows that remain in the table from the above find.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why are you using front end code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just attach this one as an example and include the search before to call:

```
showPage = function(page) {
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".content").each(function(n) {
        if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
            $(this).show();
    });        
}
```

Comment: But before you do it just to hide the not needed info with filtering. Then on the "each" method you will be able to control what to show and what not